# Why can't PHP take Malayalam font?

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3

I can't get Malayalam font while searching some Malayalam words, and searching Malayalam words like `കാര്യങ്ങള്‍` it would get a code like `%E0%B4%95%E0%B4%BE%E0%B4%B0%E0%B5%8D%E0%B4%AF%E0%B4%99%E0%B5%8D%E0%B4%99%E0%B4%B3%E0%B5%8D%E2%80%8D`. I don't know what is happening in server side. I am using codeigniter. My HTML is

```
<input name="search" id="search" type="text" class="dh_home_05" placeholder="Search"/>
<div style="float:right;"><img src="<?=base_url()?>images/new_search_btn.jpg" class="wholesearch"></div>
```

My Javascript code is

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#search').keypress(function (e) {
        var key = e.which;
        if(key == 13) { // the enter key code
            $('.wholesearch').click();
            return false;
        }
    });

    $('.wholesearch').click(function(){
        if($('#search').val() != ''){
            $str = $('#search').val();
            $str = $str.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, ''); // trim
            //$str = $str.toLowerCase();

            $from = "����������������������/_,:;";
            $to   = "aaaaeeeeiiiioooouuuunc------";

            for ($i = 0, $l = $from.length ; $i < $l; $i++) {
                $str = $str.replace(new RegExp($from.charAt($i), 'g'), $to.charAt($i));
            }
            //$str = $str.replace(/[^a-z0-9 -]/g, ' ') // remove invalid chars

            $str = $str.replace(/\s+/g, '-') // collapse whitespace and replace by -

            .replace(/-+/g, '-'); // collapse dashes
            window.location =  "<?=base_url();?>search/common/"+$str;
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Can anyone help me how to use Malayalam font in php?
My php function is:

```
public function common($wd){
    print_r($wd);die;
}
```

I print that `$wd` but the result is:

```
%E0%B4%95%E0%B4%BE%E0%B4%B0%E0%B5%8D%E0%B4%AF%E0%B4%99%E0%B5%8D%E0%B4%99%E0%B4%B3%E0%B5%8D%E2%80%8D
```

Comment: Have you made sure that the page is UTF-8 encoded? --- Also please edit your question. The formatting hurts.

Comment: <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8"> this  code is also placed in the html page

Answer (score 0):

Add this stylesheet in your header section

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Baloo+Chettan" rel="stylesheet">
```

In your stylesheet

```
.malayalamfont{font-family: 'Baloo Chettan', cursive;font-size: 15px;}
```

In your view page(html part)

```
<p class="malayalamfont">your text</p>
```